# translating C into ARM assembly

Tags: c, assembly, arm, translate

So i have this code in C that solves a Sudoku board and I want to translate it into an assembly program that reads a board from the file board.txt Output should be the solved board in the same format printed to the stdout output.I am using Jgrasp so I was wondering if there was a way to just convert it or do i have to just go line by line in my code and translate it to ARM?

here is the c code:

```
int rowOK(int board[9][9], int row) {
   int index;
   int count[10];

   for (index=0; index<10; index++)
      count[index] = 0;

   for (index=0; index<9; index++)
      count[board[row][index]]++;

   for (index=1; index<10; index++)
      if (count[index] > 1)
         return 0;

   return 1;
}

int colOK(int board[9][9], int col) {
   int row;
   int seen=0x0;

   for (row=0; row<9; row++){
      if ((board[row][col] != 0) &&
           (seen&(0x1<<board[row][col] == 1)))
         return 0;
      else
         seen=seen|(0x1<<board[row][col]);
   }

   return 1;
}

int boxOK(int board[9][9], int row, int col) {
   int roff;
   int coff;
   int seen = 0x0;

   for (roff=0; roff<3; roff++)
      for (coff=0; coff<3; coff++)
         if ((board[row+roff][col+coff] != 0) &&
              ((seen & (0x1 << board[row+roff][col+coff])) != 0))
            return 0;
         else
            seen = seen | (0x1 << board[row+roff][col+coff]);

   return 1;
}

int status(int board[9][9]) {
   int index;
   int row;
   int col;

   for (index=0; index<9; index++)
      if ((rowOK(board,index) == 0) ||
           (colOK(board,index) == 0))
         return 0;

   for (row=0; row<9; row=row+3)
      for (col=0; col<9; col=col+3)
         if (boxOK(board,row,col) == 0)
            return 0;

   return 1;
}

int solve(int board[9][9]) {
   int guess;
   int row;
   int col;
   int emptyrow = -1;
   int emptycol = -1;

   for (row=0; row<9; row++)
      for (col=0; col<9; col++)
         if (board[row][col] ==0) {
            emptyrow = row;
            emptycol = col;
         }

   if (emptyrow < 0)
      return 1;

   for (guess = 1; guess<10; guess++) {
      board[emptyrow][emptycol] = guess;
      if (status(board) == 1)
         if (solve(board) == 1)
            return 1;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are free compilers available (such as GCC) that can take ARM code and convert it into assembly for you.  If you use GCC, I think you just need to use the `-S` option.

Comment: I think David's answer above is "acceptable enough", as he's pointing out a directly way of converting the source code above to assembler. If the OP is asking SO members to outright translate the code manually, then it's not really a question.

Comment: i was just wondering if there was a compiler out there so i dont have to do it all myself make it a bit easier but if i have to code everything myself then thats fine

Comment: what do you think compilers do?